# `or` function in Scheme misbehaving

Tags: scheme, lambda-calculus

I am trying to write an `or` function in Scheme

```
(define or
  (lambda (p q) p p q))
```

If I do `(or #t #f)` I get `#f`.

What is the problem in what I am doing?

I saw `λpq.ppq` in a video on youTube.

Comment: are you sure? I ran your code and it works as expected

Comment: I added a screencap it's not working for me?

Comment: (so that the readers can try your example without having to type it in)

Comment: Unless you're trying to learn about the lambda calculus specifically, the video you found probably isn't very useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

The correct Lambda Calculus definitions are

```
(define or (lambda (p q) (p p q)))        ; (or p q) = {p AND p} OR {{NOT p} AND q}

(define xor (lambda (p q) (p (not q) q))) ; (xor p q) = {p AND {NOT q}} OR {{NOT p} AND q}

(define not (lambda (t) (lambda (p q) (t q p))))   ; ((not t) p q) = (t q p)
```

(note the parens!). But `#t` and `#f` won't work with these. They expect

```
(define true (lambda (p q) p))    ; (true p q) = p

(define false (lambda (p q) q))   ; (false p q) = q
```

You can check it with

```
((or true false) #t #f)  ; #t

((xor false false) #t #f) ; #f

((xor true false) #t #f)  ; #t
```

---

With *your* definition there's a set of parentheses missing:

```
(define or (lambda (p q)  p p q  ))
           ;            ^^     ^^
```

It reduces as:

```
(or #t #f)
=
(let ([p #t] [q #f])
   p
   p
   q )
=
(let ([p #t] [q #f])
   q )
=
#f
```

To cause an application of `p` to `p` and `q` we need to enclose the form in parentheses, like this: `(p p q)`. Without them you just have three consecutive expressions, three variables, and only the last one's value is returned, as is, as the overall result. Which is the value of `q`. Which is `#f`.

Comment: I was trying it with the syntax 
(define or (lambda (p q) (p p q)))
But as you said it was't working with #t and #f and I didn't understand why.
(define t (lambda (p q) p))
(define f (lambda (p q) q))
((or t t)#t #t) -> t
((or t f)#t #f) -> t
((or f t)#f #t) -> f * wrong
((or f f)#f #f) -> t
Using if makes it work as intended but using it your way with still gives me the wrong output for the third case. I don't want  {p AND p} OR {{NOT p} AND q} that's not right I want {p AND p} OR {p AND q}

Comment: I tested my code in DrRacket. It works *as is*. Using `if` makes it normal Scheme / Racket code. Using it as in this answer makes it a Scheme code which *implements* the "if", *lambda calculus* way. I assumed *that* was the nature of your question.

Comment: What I am trying to write I saw in a video on youtube: lambdapq.ppq can you tell me how to write this.

Comment: aha, then my answer is right. you saw λpq.ppq which is a LC syntax where application is implied. In regular Scheme syntax it is exactly what I've shown you: (lambda (p q) (p p q)) where application is shown by parenthesization.

Comment: also, p&p || p&q == p || p&q == p.

Comment: If it's right can you explain to me why I am still getting #f for ((or false true)#f #t)

Comment: wait, no, you test it wrong! it MUST be `((or ...whatever...) #t #f)` by definition.

Comment: the "true" value in LC means "pick the first one of the two arguments supplied". if you supplied it  #f and #t, it correctly picked the first. which is just misleading you. give it #t first, so when `true` selects the first, it will be #t. you could also use 1 and 0, for example. try it.

Comment: Sorry what is LC? I am trying to look it up, but I can't find it. I am a beginner to scheme and thank you you have been very helpful.

Comment: Lambda Calculus. if this helps, you can *accept* the most helpful answer. :)